# To prove that $\frac{\left|{z-r}\right|}{1-r}$ is bounded on the approach region $\Omega_\alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

I'm reading the Real and Complex Analysis of Rudin and having trouble with the following argument of the middle of page 242, chapter 11 harmonic functions.

> The definition of $\Omega_\alpha$ shows that $\frac{\left|{z-r}\right|}{1-r}$ is bounded in $\Omega_\alpha$ where $r=\left|z\right|$

Here $\Omega_\alpha$ is an approach region on the complex plane defined by interior of the boundary which consists of the circle of radius $\alpha$ centered at the origin with the 2 tangents lines starting from 1.
Visually, it is a region like the following figure.
[image: The approach region of radius $\alpha$]

(I'm very sorry with the poor figure. I really don't know how I can get a well-drown figure or what programs to use.)

Obviously, the given value $\frac{\left|{z-r}\right|}{1-r}$ is bounded in the disk of radius $\alpha$ since $r<\alpha$ here. But how can I prove it in the remaining triangular region? It seems like the given one approaches some limit when $z$ gets closer to 1, but I don't see how this can be proved with either geometric argument or numerical approach. Thanks for any help.

Comment: IMHO, [Geogebra](http://geogebra.org/) is a pretty simple program to plot those kind of pictures.

Comment: This is pretty helpful. I should update the uploaded one soon. Thanks!